# How to set up Blender on a Windows Server?

Tags: installation

How to set up Blender on a server to run Crowd Render for myself and the two other Blender users in my office?

We asked IT about creating a render farm with some spare PCs we have around, but they said we wouldn't be able to due to IT Security. But we would be allowed to run "a Windows 2019 or Linux server. Can be virtual or physical."

I'm not familiar with any of this, so is there any documentation available on setting something like this up?

Comment: That's external software, not part of Blender which is what this Q&A site covers. Try looking at the docs for it which seem to be [here](https://www.crowd-render.com/documentation-v030)!

Comment: For this post, I'm not asking about Crowd Render. I'm asking about how to setup Blender on a server. We'll need to get Blender running before we install the Blender Add on.

Comment: Ok. How about [this](https://gist.github.com/zocker-160/0688a4902421158b66f52dff3966058a)?